# PyQt: construct contents of a Chart in a worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 to create a visualisation, I have a chart view

```
self._chartView = QChartView(QChart())
```

and visualise several line segments in it:

```
# construct line segments -> lineSegments

for ls in lineSegments:
    self._chartView.chart().addSeries(ls)
```

To keep the GUI responsive I want to move the creation of the line segments into a worker thread. When the thread has finished, I would like to call `addSeries` to put the line segments under the chart (possibly connect it to the `finished` slot). However, I get the warning

```
Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

when calling `addSeries` in the main thread. What possibilities do I have to work around this problem while still moving the creation of the line segments into an worn thread?